# Underline node text in jstree

Tags: jstree

I want to underline the node text in jstree. Is there an API available to do so?
Can there be a class attached to the node that does so? The underline should not go even if the node gets renamed.

Comment: Why don't you just use css text-decoration:underline?

Comment: The thing is, if I use that, I will have to manage it from several places, including when I rename a node. This option is always available to be implemented at the last, if jstree API doesn't support any other easy option. Anyway, thanks for replying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it done through the "a_attr" attribute in the type configuration of the tree. Whatever, you specify in here gets applied to the text

```
"nodeType": {
                "icon": "folder-icon.png",
                "valid_children": [],
                "a_attr": { "style": "text-decoration: underline" }
            },
```